# How to properly save images on device; just for displaying them inside my App later

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, storage

the user of my App is taking about 8 pictures a day. These pictures get saved on the device and should only be viewed inside my app i. e. not in "Photos". The photos should be viewed in something like a gallary. But I dont know how to realize this yet.

Now my question, after you viewed the code below. **Is this a acceptable way to do this kind of task?** Basically I am saving the photos to the NSDocumentDirectory. Later I like to access them by putting them in an array of UIImages which just needs to be displayed somehow.

Currenty I am saving the photos like this. These pictures will be accessed by the user:

```
        **UIImage *combined == //an UIImage

        NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(combined);
        NSString *filePath = [[self buildDocumentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self buildPictureName]]; //Add the file name
        [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
        NSLog(@"CameraController: Image saved on disk: %@", [self buildPictureName]);
```

Helpfunction1:

```
- (NSString *)buildPictureName{
    int currentTime = mTimerSpan*i;
    NSString *imageName = @"bg_session=";
    NSString *sessionNumberAsString =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)mCurrentSessionNumber];
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:sessionNumberAsString];
    return [imageName stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
}
```

Helpfunction2:

```
- (NSString *)buildDocumentsPath{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsPath; 
}
```

Getting the image back from the device, I like to build a fuction which gets all the images into an array of UIImages????:

```
NSString *filePath = [[self buildDocumentsPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self buildPictureName]];
    NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
```

Comment: What's the question, exactly?

Comment: If  this an acceptable way to do this kind of task? I am new to iOS. I an not sure if there is a better/easier way to do this. Do you think I am on the right track? (see my 2nd paragraph)

Comment: Perhaps I'm just being dense, but I don't see what you mean by "acceptable". You can't ask an _opinion_-based question on Stack Overflow, so I don't quite get what you're looking for. You certainly must not build "an array of UIImages", however; your app will crash for lack of memory.

Comment: so, for my intention (to display the images to the user in a galery) it is correct/doable by storing these pictures using "NSDocumentDirectory"? Or do you know a better way?

Comment: Sure, it sounds like a great place. But the exact location will depend on your needs. My book has some discussion of the merits of various possible places to store stuff: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch36.html#_the_sandbox